# Python web scraping, can't 'click' next page

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm grabbing data off a page, filling out the form fields as follows:

```
url = 'http://www.theurl.co.uk/Enquiry.asp'

values = {'PageSize' : '20', 'SortField' : '1', 'SortOrder' : 'ASC'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)          
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
source = urllib2.urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
```

Then extracting my data from the soup. My problem is that I then need to move to the next 20 results, the next page button is controlled with the following line in the source:

```
<input type="submit" name="Action" value=" > " style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; color: #000080; font-weight: bold">
```

How can I possibly do this without moving to using mechanize (which I've not used before); is this possible?

Many Thanks

Comment: You need to find out what field is telling it to go to the next page and add it to your parameters - probably either a 'next' or some kind of 'startAt' value.

Comment: Observe the url change after clicking the next button.And if possible give us the working URL so that we can observe it.

Comment: The url doesn't change after clicking the next button.

Comment: the url may not change on the browser address bar... however you can see what url is being obtained using the firefox tamper data (first choice)... and firefox live http headers... to see the activity behind the screen... This will tell you what parameters you need to supply to get to page 2 or more. If you post the URL i can try.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the form elements action attribute. If there isn't one, then it will be using the same URL. I'd bet theres a page number value in the form data somewhere, that you'll need to use.

Comment: The only page number value I can find is beneath the next button:

    <input type="hidden" name="iPage" value="1">&nbsp;
    <font color="#000080" size="1">Page: 1 of 4</font>

But adding 'iPage' : '2' to my dictionary of values doesn't load up the second page of results...

Comment: the url may not change on the browser address bar... however you can see what url is being obtained using the firefox tamper data (first choice)... and firefox live http headers... to see the activity behind the screen... This will tell you what parameters you need to supply to get to page 2 or more. If you post the URL i can try.